# Power Query: recursive function to append elements in a table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to use a recursive function to append values from a list to a table, however the code below only show me the first and second results:

```
let
    Source = {"second", "third", "forth", "fith", "seventh", "eighth"},
    Count = List.Count(Source),
    Table = Table.FromRecords({[sequence = "first"]}, type table[sequence = text]),

    appendTbl = (x as list, n as number, tbl as table) => 
    let
        appTable = Table.InsertRows(Table, n, {[sequence = Source{n}]}),
        Check = if n = (Count-1) then @appendTbl(x, n+1, appTable) else appTable
    in
        Check,

    Result = appendTbl(Source, 0, Table)
in
    Result
```

[image]

Can anyone please give me a help? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its kind of hard to tell if you are using the number to designate the spot in the table you want to insert, or the number of times you want to duplicate the array before inserting it into the table

That said, you can combine tables with Table.Combine() after converting the list to a table with Table.FromList(). If you need to append it multiple times then just use List.Repeat on the list. If you need to use the Count variable in your function, you have to send it there  appendTbl = (x as list, n as number, tbl as table, count as number) =>

some sample codes  that probably don't do exactly what you want

```
let  Source = {"second", "third", "forth", "fith", "seventh", "eighth"},
AppendCount=2, //# times to append the list onto the table
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(List.Repeat(Source,AppendCount), Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "sequence"}}),
Table = Table.FromRecords({[sequence = "first"]}, type table[sequence = text]),
combined= Table.Combine({Table, #"Renamed Columns"})
in  combined
```

or

```
let  Source = {"second", "third", "forth", "fith", "seventh", "eighth"},
Table = Table.FromRecords({[sequence = "first"]}, type table[sequence = text]),
appendTbl = (x as list, n as number, tbl as table) => // append list x to table tbl, n times on column sequence
    let #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(List.Repeat(x,n), Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "sequence"}}),
    combined= Table.Combine({tbl, #"Renamed Columns"})
in  combined,
 Result = appendTbl(Source, 2, Table)  // append Source to Table, 2 times
in Result
```